# Why doesn't my java code print out the array list?

Tags: java, arraylist, printing

```
package booking;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarProfile {

    static int year;
    static int cylinders;
    static int plateNum;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int reg = 1;
        ArrayList <CarProfile> list = new ArrayList <CarProfile>();

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(reg == 1) {                   
            System.out.println("Enter manf. year");
            year = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter num. of cyl");
            cylinders = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter plateNum");
            plateNum = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("If you wish to register another car press 1, otherwise press anything");
            reg = sc.nextInt(); 
        }

        Arrays.toString(list.toArray());    
    }
}
```

This is the code. I also tried to use a for loop with System but didn't get any luck there either. So what am I missing here?
I don't know what else to type, it is a really simple question.

Comment: Override `toString` in CarProfile

Comment: at which line you are printing ?

Comment: Your code never says to print anything ...

Comment: Why are you using `static` for the class fields? It means that _every_ instance of `CarProfile` shares the same fields. I don't think you want this.

Comment: I don't see where you are actually adding something to the list.

Comment: *"otherwise press **anything**"* I enter `X` and get **`InputMismatchException`**

Comment: I was about to give an answer then I notice your logic is very confusing. First, `CarProfile` should be it's own `Class`. Second, you are using static variables. Third, you never add anything to the `List`. Fourth, you only print out if the user wants to register another car.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling `System.out.println` on the code, The code doesn't knows its suppose to print it out. so replace

```
Arrays.toString(list.toArray());
```

With

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `System.out.println(list)` be better, and wouldn't it also be better if something was actually added to the list?

Comment: The question was about why it's not printing out what response of the OP's code. I have just told the OP how to print out what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: when I add to the list using 'list.add(year)' it doesn't work. @Sedrick